# Count with exists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is this query not returning the count of the results? How do I get it to show the count

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS MWith
FROM member   m
JOIN Channel  mc ON mc.MemberID = m.id
JOIN Client   c  ON c.id = m.clientid
JOIN packages p  ON p.id = m.packageid
WHERE Enroll > '2018'
AND EXISTS  (
            SELECT * FROM
            activity a 
            WHERE a.memberid = m.id
            AND a.code IN ('785', 'a599')
            ) 
GROUP BY m.id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
MWith
1
1
1
```

Comment: Why do you think it isn't returning the count of results from that query? The formatting sure makes this difficult to read but it is a basic aggregate query.

Comment: Without your data, do you pretend we answer your question? The normal answer would be your where filter is filtering all the records, so if I were your I would start from there.

Comment: What do you mean by *not returning the count of the results*? Does it throw an error or it returns 0? And please provide sample data.

Comment: @JaimeDrq Added the output

Comment: Is that the output you want or the output you are getting? My guess is that isn't what you want and you expect to get 3? Remove the group by if that is the case. Provide some actual details if that isn't.

Comment: @JaimeDrq "pretend" in english is very different from "pretende" in spanish ;) pay attention. Pretend is called false cagnates by that.

Comment: @statosdotcom, thanks for the point... I always do the same when I am writting fast. When I said "pretend", I wanted to say "expect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty set is because of the clause `group by` .

The workarounds are:

1. Remove a `GROUP BY`, because m.id anyway is not part of the output
2. Use `GROUP BY ALL`

**An original example:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MWith
FROM member m
    JOIN Channel mc
        ON mc.MemberID = m.id
    JOIN Client c
        ON c.id = m.clientid
    JOIN packages p
        ON p.id = m.packageid
WHERE Enroll > '2018'
      AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM activity a
    WHERE a.memberid = m.id
          AND a.code IN ( '785', 'a599' )
)
--   GROUP BY m.id;
```

**Other, simpler examples to show a difference:**

```
-- returns an empty resultset
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases
WHERE 1=0
GROUP BY name

-- returns: a single row with 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases
WHERE 1=0

-- Another example with GROUP BY ALL
-- it returns one row per grouped value, with expected count = 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases
WHERE 1=0
GROUP BY ALL name
```

Comment: Why does the group by cause to not return the count in this case?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause may be correct, but it depends on what the OP wants.

Comment: Why the group by would be the causer? if it returns 0, if you split 0 in groups, all the groups must return 0 too huh?

Comment: @Aaron it does return the count, grouped by the id as you told it to do. If you don't want to count each id then remove it from the group by.

Comment: @Aaron, I added some simple examples. The GROUP BY just filters empty resultsets out.

Comment: Ok... I understand your point, but the question doesn't explicitly say that the problem is with an empty output. If so, you are right.

Comment: @JaimeDrq, Aaron added the output part little bit later. Initially the question was why GROUP BY produces no results, while expected some rows with zero values

Comment: Ok... sorry I edited the question to indent the code and I haven't been ever able to see the output provided.